# Django DisallowedHost with the asterisk in the begining of domain

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have Django (1.6.10) with Nginx (1.7.9) and uwsgi (1.9.17.1-debian) proxy between them.
Sometimes I see such error in my email:

`DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '*.example.com'.`

(example.com is my domain, **the asterisks between the dot is very confusing**)

I have server with subdomains (over 2000) so I configured my Django this way:
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', '.example.com']`

Nginx is configured this way:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:///tmp/jsp.sock;
        include     uwsgi_params;
    }
...
```

From traceback I can get only that this error happens on ie6, on secured (https) version of site (I support both http and https), but I couldn't reproduce it installing virtual machine.

```
<WSGIRequest
path:/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': '',
 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/etc/nginx/html',
 'HTTPS': 'on',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'none',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_HOST': '*.example.com',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.2)',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '<ip here>',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '39282',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'REQUEST_URI': '/',
 u'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'example.com',
 'SERVER_PORT': '443',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'UWSGI_APPID': '*.foundjob.ru|',
 'uwsgi.node': 'Ubuntu-1304-raring-64-minimal',
 'uwsgi.version': '1.9.17.1-debian',
 'wsgi.errors': <open file 'wsgi_errors', mode 'w' at 0x7fbcfd0f14b0>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in function uwsgi_sendfile>,
 'wsgi.input': <uwsgi._Input object at 0x7fbd025bae28>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'https',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

Comment: What's in `uwsgi_params` file?

Comment: It is nginx conf file out of the package https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/uwsgi_params

Comment: That means that browser send header `Host: *.example.com`? You could check it in nginx's logs, but you should modify log format first since nginx's default format doesn't write `$http_host`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen I had tried to send header ```Host: *.example.com``` with curl, but got nothing

Comment: Hey @FeroxTL, commenting here hoping you found a fix for this (and perhaps a way to reproduce the error). I tried doing what you did (curl) but didn't manage to reproduce it.

Comment: @chuck-logan-lim Try not to use character *, use regular expressions like [a-z] or w+, this seems to be the only way. For example server_name     ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.domainA\.com$;
 Have a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html Comment here if it works

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using a regular expression instead of the wildcard

```
# server_name example.com *.example.com;
server_name example.com ~^\w+\.example\.com$;
```

With this expression, only subdomains using the the letters a-z, the digits 0-9 and the underscore character _ is valid in the subdomain part.